# M365 group email change via Graph API

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to change M365 Group email alias [Nickname] with use of Graph API. 
Below HTTP call returns 204 [as expected]. Group email stays the same :? I have waited several hours. 
I am able to change other group properties [description, display name etc.] with this call

```
 {
    "inputs": {
        "method": "PATCH",
        "uri": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/GROUPID",
        "headers": {
            "Content-type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": {
            "mailNickname": "_Display12345"
        },
        "authentication": {
            "audience": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
            "clientId": "",
            "secret": "",
            "tenant": "",
            "type": "ActiveDirectoryOAuth"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be due to insufficient permissions. Make sure you are allowing the permission according to your account type from [Update group - MSFT Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

> | Permission type | Permissions (from least to most privileged) |
> | --- | --- |
> | Delegated (work or school account) | Group.ReadWrite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All |
> | Delegated (personal Microsoft account) | Not supported. |
> | Application | Group.ReadWrite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All |

Now try making the required changes to your attributes (i.e., mailNickname in your case).

[image]

To make sure this is working try fetching the details of your group which gives the response with updated attributes.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<GroupId>
```

**REFERENCES:** [Get group - MSFT Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: It was permissions issue - thx for help

Answer (score 0):

I have repro the issue the API is working fine and I am able to update the alias [Nickname]
[image]

can you please try this in Graph explorer and see if it works.